# VHDL - How do you connect 1 output-bit to several 1-bit signals?

Tags: vhdl

Assume that I have an and gate with an output. The problem is that I want to connect its output so several other components. So I need to make many "copies" of the output from this and gate so I can connect many components to this output. Can you do this with signals and aliases or how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to make copies - any number of other things can "listen" to a particular signal.  For example:

```
....
architecture a of entity_name is
  signal and_out : std_logic;
begin
  -- drive the signal we want to use in multiple places, just a normal signal assignment
  and_out <= in1 and in2; 

  -- one block using the signal
  some_block_instance: entity work.some_block
  port map (some_input => and_out,...); 

  -- another block using the signal
  some_other_block_instance: entity work.some_other_block
  port map (some_other_input => and_out,...);

  another_signal <= and_out or in3; -- a signal assignment reading the signal
....
```

Comment: I will try this. Omg. I have overworked this so much. I even made a "copy"/"splitter" component that copied the input to several outputs. But I will try this more obvious and simple solution that you gave me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to find an introductory VHDL reference.  You might try googling for **VHDL Made Easy**, a book by David Pellerin and Douglas Taylor.

No you don't need to make copies.  You only need one unique signal for each 'net'.

From des.vhdl:

```
DB1: bidir port map (Z => DATA(7),Y => DIN(1), OE => DOE, A => DOUT(1));
DB2: bidir port map (Z => DATA(6),Y => DIN(2), OE => DOE, A => DOUT(2));
DB3: bidir port map (Z => DATA(5),Y => DIN(3), OE => DOE, A => DOUT(3));
DB4: bidir port map (Z => DATA(4),Y => DIN(4), OE => DOE, A => DOUT(4));
DB5: bidir port map (Z => DATA(3),Y => DIN(5), OE => DOE, A => DOUT(5));
DB6: bidir port map (Z => DATA(2),Y => DIN(6), OE => DOE, A => DOUT(6));
DB7: bidir port map (Z => DATA(1),Y => DIN(7), OE => DOE, A => DOUT(7));
DB8: bidir port map (Z => DATA(0),Y => DIN(8), OE => DOE, A => DOUT(8));

DO_EN:  invbuf port map ( A => DOE_N, Z => DOE);
```

The component declarations:

```
package des_pack is


    component bidir
        port (
            Z:      inout   std_logic;
            Y:      out std_logic;
            OE:     in  std_logic;
            A:      in  std_logic
        );
    end component;
...

    component invbuf
        port (
            A:      in  std_logic;
            Z:      out std_logic
        );
```

The signal DOE declaration:

```
architecture behave of des is
...
    signal DOE:                 std_logic;
...
begin
```

This is from a VHDL implementation of DES that's GPLv3. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25980826/vhdl_des.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to connect an AND gate output to many other components. Being pedantic you would actually connect it to ports on those components : can we assume all those ports are input ports? If so...

create a simple signal, and just connect it to the output port and all the input ports. Martin beat me to it with the details...